# Are the two JVM instances making confusion to remotely debug

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, tomcat, jvm

To remotely debug my application running in tomcat7 over ubuntu server I set the following variables;

```
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat7
export CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat7/
export JPDA_ADDRESS=8090
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

then I went to tomcat home folder `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin` and write the following line to run tomcat in debug mode.

```
\#./catalina.sh jpda start
```

then I try to remotely connect, I got **Connection Refused**. I checked with `netstat -ln` both 80 and 8090 ports were listening, then I stop tomcat using `service tomcat7 stop` , then my 80 port stops listening and I was able to remotely connect as well.

As a learner I need to know what is the reason of this? Is that something like 2 jvm started one with debugger and one simple and doing some confusion ? but I have it on another port why I am unable to connect to that?

Comment: Here's a thought that you can check the pid of process listening on 8090 before and after you stop the tomcat service.

Comment: just a sidenote: you shouldn't allow those ports to be accessible over the open internet since debugging allows arbitrary code execution. binding the debugging socket to localhost and tunneling over SSH is preferable

Comment: @the8472 thnx for ur reply, but m very sorry I'm really not understding what u told has any link to my problem, kindly can u xplain may be I am missing something ...very thankful to u in advance

Comment: Try running tomcat on unprivileged port. That may be an issue with port 80 that your tomcat instance is listening to. Maybe it will work with port 8080 for instance (or any greater than 1024).